# Cannot find snort in /etc

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, snort

Earlier I was trying to open `snort` by doing `cd /etc/snort` and it was working perfectly fine. Then I upgraded my Ubuntu and now whenever I do `cd /etc/snort`, it says `bash: cd: /etc/snort: No such file or directory`.

So then I tried installing `snort` by doing `sudo apt-get install snort`. But it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
snort is already the newest version (2.9.7.0-5build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up snort (2.9.7.0-5build1) ...
cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/snort/snort.debian.conf.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package snort (--configure):
 installed snort package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snort
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone help me with this? I'm a total beginner in Ubuntu.

Comment: Do `dpkg -L snort` to see files installed by the package.

Comment: You never gave us a hint why you do `cd /etc/snort` in the first place. You wrote you wanted to "open snort"; what do you mean by that? Start it? (then that would be the wrong command); configure it? Or what else?